# How do I filter or retain duplicates in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have one text string which is having some duplicate characters (FFGGHHJKL). These can be made unique by using the positive lookahead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.)(?=.*?\1)//g']
```

For example, with `"FFEEDDCCGG"`, the output is `"FEDCG"`.

My question is how to make it work on the numbers  (Ex. 212 212 43 43 5689 6689 5689 71 81 === output should be 212 43 5689 6689 71 81) ? Also if we want to have only duplicate records to be given as the output from a file having n rows

```
212 212 43 43 5689 6689 5689 71 81
66 66 67 68 69 69 69 71 71 52
..
```

Output:

```
212 212 43 43 5689 5689
66 66 69 69 69 71 71
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your regular expression only removes *consecutive* duplicates, but your "number" example shows removing non-consecutive duplicates, too. Which do you want?

Comment: @Kennedy- yes sir you are right. I wanted for the numbers which may not be consequetive, this is working now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is untested, but should print out only the duplicates.

```
my $line = "212 212 43 43 5689 6689 5689 71 81\n";
chomp $line;

my %seen;
my @order;
foreach my $elem (split /\s+/, $line) {
  ++$seen{$elem};
  push @order, $elem if $seen{$elem} == 2;
}

foreach my $elem (@order) {
  print "$elem " x $seen{$elem};
}
print "\n";
```

For removing duplicates, you can now:

```
print "$_ " for keys %seen;
```

BUT that doesn't retain the order. You can do something similar as I did for printing out the dupes only. Or use a module like [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::Hash::Indexed) (thanks, daxim) or [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-IxHash/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm#EXAMPLE)

Comment: Teaching an old dog a new trick: promote `Tie::Hash::Indexed` over `Tie::IxHash`.

Comment: Hi 
thanks for the help :) 

I modified it a bit and the final code is (Hope someone else will also get benefit)


#!/usr/bin/perl
#

open (MYFILE, "FILENAME");

foreach $line (<MYFILE>) {

    chomp $line;

    my %seen;

    my @order;

    foreach my $elem (split /\s+/, $line) {

        ++$seen{$elem};

        push @order, $elem if $seen{$elem} == 2;

     }
     
     foreach my $elem (@order) {

         print "$elem " x $seen{$elem};
     }

     print "\n";
 }

close (MYFILE);

Thank u all once again

Answer (score 0):

For the first part

```
$ cat prog.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -lp

my %seen;
$_ = join " " => map $seen{$_}++ ? () : $_ => split;

$ echo 212 212 43 43 5689 6689 5689 71 81 | ./prog.pl
212 43 5689 6689 71 81
```

For the second part

```
$ cat prog.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -lp

my %dups;
my @nums = split;
++$dups{$_} for @nums;

$_ = join " " => grep $dups{$_} > 1 => @nums;

$ cat input
212 212 43 43 5689 6689 5689 71 81
66 66 67 68 69 69 69 71 71 52

$ ./prog.pl input
212 212 43 43 5689 5689
66 66 69 69 69 71 71
```